# Matlab & Arduino serial communication

Tags: matlab, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to get some basic serial communication up and running. My arduino code is shown below.

```
   void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);

      Serial.println('a');
      char a = 'b';
      while (a != 'a')
      {
        a = Serial.read();
      }
    }
    void loop()
    {
    }
```

and my matlab code:

```
delete(instrfindall);
s = serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
set(s, 'StopBits', 1);
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
set(s, 'Terminator', 'LF');
fopen(s);

% VERIFY SERIAL COMMUNICATION HAS BEEN SETUP
a = 'b';
while (a~='a')
        a = fread(s,1,'uchar');
end
if (a == 'a')
    disp('Serial read')
end
fprintf(s,'%c','a');
mxbox = msgbox('Serial Communication Initialized'); uiwait(mxbox);
```

The matlab code executes and I get the message box telling me that it has initialised, however the variable **a** is not read successfully and the while loop exits prematurely, debugging I found that it actually only loops for one iteration and then continues. **'Serial read'** is never displayed.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Note**

adding `disp(size(a));disp(double(a));` after the `fread` yielded output **1  0** and no output respectively

Comment: For debugging purposes, could you add `disp(size(a));disp(double(a));` after the `fread` line and append the output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your conditions are a logical negation, but it is not. Both conditions are false for `a=[]` (or `a=['a','b']`). Reading nothing could explain the behaviour you observed. Try this code instead:

```
a = 'b';
while (~strcmpi(a,'a'))
        a = fread(s,1,'uchar');
end
if (strcmpi(a,'a'))
    disp('Serial read')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I add this code it gets stuck in the while loop, so I am not reading anything. I've also added the output as your previous comment suggested to the end of the question.

Comment: @TomPower: I can't give you any hint why it's not receiving anything, but just a comment on what you are doing. There is a Arduino support package (http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-matlab.html) for matlab and there is a java interface (http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) which could easily be used in matlab (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html). It might be an alternative if you fail to solve this problem.